# NodeJS - AJAX POST 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, ejs

I am trying to send values from one file to another on click of items displayed.
While doing so, I am getting the error:

```
POST http://localhost:4000/todo/addToCart 404 (Not Found)    jquery-3.3.1.js:9600
```

My **app.js** file:

```
//More codes above to set-up express and all
app.use(express.static('./public'));
todoController(app); //give todocontroller the reference to express
app.listen(4000); //listen on a port
console.log('server is running');
```

**Controller:**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/todo', function(req, resp) {
    Todo.find({}, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('get method');
      resp.render('todo', {
        todos: data
      });
    });
  });
  //Few More Code
  app.post('/todo', urlencodedParser, function(req, resp) {
    console.log('post method');
    resp.render('addToCart', {
      data: req.body
    });
  });
};
```

**Model for data interaction:**

```
$('li').on('click', function() { //when user clicks on an item in the list
  var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-"); //traps the item user clicked on
  alert(item);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/todo/addToCart', //+item append that item to the url
    success: function(item) {
      location.reload(); //refresh the page
    }
  });
});
```

**Parent ejs:**

```
<div id="todo-table">
  <form id="todoForm" method="post" action="/todo">
    <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add new Item..." required />
    <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
    <ul>
      <% for (var i=0;i<todos.length; i++){ %>
      <li>
        <%=todos[i].item%>
      </li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Child ejs**(to which I need to re-direct):

```
<div id="itemSelect">Selected Item:
  <form id="addToCart" method="post" action="/addToCart">
    <button type="submit" id="btnCheckOut">Check out</button>
    <%=data.item%>
  </form>
</div>
```

Please help. I am new, kindly point out my mistake.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The route you created on your nodejs server here:

```
app.post('/todo', urlencodedParser, function (req, resp) {
  console.log('post method');
  resp.render('addToCart', { data: req.body });
});
```

Matches all the POST requests made to the `/todo` endpoint, not the `/todo/addToCart` which doesnt exist. This is why you obtain a 404.

Your ajax request should be like so:

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
  var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-");
  alert(item);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/todo', // 'addToCart' has been removed from the path
    success: function (item) {
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```